# Why am I getting -> [WARNING] The POM for xxx is missing, no dependency in

Tags: maven-3

When I run a maven build I get a number of warnings, just like this one:

```
[WARNING] The POM for apache-log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.14 is missing, no dependency information available
```

How can I determine why I am getting this ?

Note: I do have a dependency on log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.17:compile but I can't figure out why this warning relating to apache-log4j is there. I ran mvn dependency:trace but the apache-log4j dependency doesn't appear anywhwere in the tree. I looked for it in my poms too but to no avail.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Do you have any other dependencies? Perhaps one of those has a dependency on `apache-log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.14` which it doesn't include in its own jar.

Comment: Have you looked at the dependency tree via `mvn dependency:tree` ?

Comment: @khmarbaise - I have looked at the dependency tree and I don't see any dependany on apache-log4j. Chris - that might be true but if it is true, then how can i figure out which jar has created this dependency (as I haven't explicitly in my own poms).